# Awk: Printing lines backwards with line number and wordcount

Tags: text-processing, awk

Using the awk command, I am to display lines 3-5 backwards of a file i have created and before the outputted line, the line number is to be displayed (i.e. line 3:). I am also to display the total wordcount of all three lines. My code is provided below. I keep obtaining an error message for the '%s' and not sure where to go from here, any help?

```
BEGIN { print("<< Start of file >>"); }

NR>=3 && NR<=5 { for (i = NF; i >= 1; i--)

                printf "%d: %s ", $i;
                print ""
                wordCount += NF;


}



END { printf "<< End of file: wordCount = %d >>\n", wordCount }
```

Here's the input file:

```
Gimme presents I want more!
Gimme presents, I did my chores!
A bicycle, a tricycle, a motor vehicle!
I deserve it, you reverse it!
Gimme presents; more, more, more
Gimme presents I need more!
```

And the out put i obtain is:

```
(FILENAME=presents FNR=3) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
        `%d: %s '
             ^ ran out for this one
```

Comment: Can you post example of your input and desired output ?

Comment: Also, you mentioned  error for `%s`. Please post the exact text of error that you're getting.

Comment: it has been updated, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Aha, I see the issue. `printf "%d: %s ", $i;` The `%d` matches for `$i` but there's nothing you provide to match for `%s`. I'll put it in an answer shortly

Answer (score 1):

#### Code bug portion

Key issue is that you have `%d: %s` format, but there's only one argument `$i` to match the format speficiers, i.e. `$i` matches with `%d` but not with `%s`.

Once you change the script as so:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { print("<< Start of file >>"); }

NR>=3 && NR<=5 { 
    for (i = NF; i >= 1; i--)
        printf "%d: %s ", i,$i;
    print ""
    wordCount += NF;


}

END { printf "<< End of file: wordCount = %d >>\n", wordCount }
```

Then there's no error, and produces output as so:

```
$ ./awk_script.awk input.txt
<< Start of file >>
7: vehicle! 6: motor 5: a 4: tricycle, 3: a 2: bicycle, 1: A 
6: it! 5: reverse 4: you 3: it, 2: deserve 1: I 
5: more 4: more, 3: more, 2: presents; 1: Gimme 
<< End of file: wordCount = 18 >>
```

#### Fixing code to match desired behavior

However, your description was:

> I am to display lines 3-5 backwards of a file i have created and before the outputted line, the line number is to be displayed (i.e. line 3:)

That means before processing each field using for-loop, you need to output line number first:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { print("<< Start of file >>"); }

NR>=3 && NR<=5 {
    printf "line %d:",NR; # display line number first
    for (i = NF; i >= 1; i--)
        printf " %s ", $i;
    print ""; 
    wordCount += NF;

}

END { printf "<< End of file: wordCount = %d >>\n", wordCount }
```

Which works as so:

```
$ ./awk_script.awk input.txt
<< Start of file >>
line 3: vehicle!  motor  a  tricycle,  a  bicycle,  A 
line 4: it!  reverse  you  it,  deserve  I 
line 5: more  more,  more,  presents;  Gimme 
<< End of file: wordCount = 18 >>
```

Comment: Wow! such a simple fix, upvote! One more thing, how would we rid the text from repeating itself with the original pattern, as it is appended to the reversed line in the output?

Comment: I figured it out, had to remove the 'print;' line!

Comment: Oops, sorry, the `print ""`  was necessary.  Occasionally small details like that escape my attention :)

Comment: It looks like you're just using `print ""` in order to tack on a newline.  How about just adding `\n` to the end of the `printf` format argument instead?  @HermanTravis

Comment: @Wildcard it will result in a bug - each iteration will print each word of *the* line on its own line.  `print ""` still serves as "record separator" so to speak

Comment: @Wildcard  That's of course if you're talking about changing `printf " %s ", $i;` into `printf " %s \n", $i;`. Remember that the printf part is inside for loop.  If you mean `printf "\n"` after (!) the for loop, then it's OK

Comment: Ah.  See, this is why I never, ever allow a `for` loop to exist in Awk without curly braces surrounding the associated action.  I missed that those two adjacent commands were not part of the same execution path.

Comment: @Wildcard Understandable, and I've seen this when tutoring C - it's much easier for students to see if there's braces. As you can guess, this isn't just `awk` thing, though. `awk` syntax comes a lot from C, and same construct works in `C` and `Java` for loops.  Personally, I'd suggest just creating mental "if-else" statement: if there's no braces after for, there's just one  command statement, else there's many. At least helps with code reading. As for writing - use whatever is easier for you and what gets the job done :)